# How to call a variable through the find method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm new to ruby on rails and here is the problem:

I'm trying to get the client name inside a loop about the car information. The car data holds an column called "belongs_to" which is the ID of the client.

The important line: `<td><%= @client.find(car.belongs_to) %></td>`

The controller:

```
  def index
    @cars = Car.all

    @client = Client.all

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.xml  { render :xml => @cars }
    end
  end
```

How would you guys do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You would use Models to achieve this:

```
class Car < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :client
end

class Client < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :cars
end
```

and in your View:

```
@car.client
```

**EDIT**

or the other way round:

```
@client.cars
# to iterate over them:
@client.cars.each do |car|
  # do something with car
end
```

Answer (score 4):

belongs_to is not a very good column name.  There is an association type called "belongs_to" where you can establish a relationship between models, where one of them "belongs_to" another model, such as:

```
class Car < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :client  # there is a column on the cars table called "client_id"
end
```

and

```
class Client < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :cars
end
```

Then you can do:

```
client = car.client
```

Take a look at [Ruby on Rails Guides - A Guide to Active Record Associations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html)

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
Client.find(car.belongs_to)
```

What you really want to do, though is have your `Car` model have something like this

```
belongs_to :client
```

And your `Client` model have

```
has_many :cars
```

Then you can simply call `@car.client` to get what you want.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you could do something like:

```
@cars.each do |car|
  car.client
end
```

and in car model, I guess you alredy have:

```
belongs_to :client
```